# Gradle version of .mavenrc

Tags: java, maven, gradle

We can set maven specific option like `JAVA_HOME`, `MAVEN_OPTS` in `$HOME/.mavenrc` file

**Does `gradle` have this feature?**

**If yes, how can we achieve this?**

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Added `gradle.properties` in `$HOME/.gradle/` but when I do `gradle --version` it's not getting picked up. Am I missing something?
`org.gradle.java.home=/path/to/jdk/home`

Comment: I've verified the same behavior.  You might pursue this in the Gradle forum if you don't get an answer here.